# How to check if two strings can be made equal by using recursion?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to practice recursion, but at the moment I don't quite understand it well...

I want to write a recursive Boolean function which takes 2 strings as arguments, and returns true if the second string can be made equal to the first by replacing some letters with a certain special character.

**I'll  demonstrate what I mean:**

Let s1 = "hello", s2 = "h%lo", where '%' is the special character.

The function will return **true** since '%' can replace "el", causing the two strings to be equal.

**Another example:**

Let s1 = "hello", s2 = "h%l".

The function will return **false** since an 'o' is lacking in the second string, and there is no special character that can replace the 'o' (h%l% would return **true**).

Now the problem isn't so much with writing the code, but with understanding how to solve the problem in general, I don't even know where to begin.

If someone could guide me in the right direction I would be very grateful, even by just using English words, I'll try to translate it to code (Java)...

Thank you.

Comment: ask your teacher or your study partner

Comment: If you want to practice recursion, I suggest you learn binary trees

Answer (score 0):

So this is relatively easy to do in Python. The method I chose was to put the first string ("hello") into an array then iterate over the second string ("h%lo") comparing the elements to those in the array. If the element was in the array i.e. 'h', 'l', 'o' then I would pop it from the array. The resulting array is then ['e','l']. The special character can be found as it is the element which does not exist in the initial array.

One can then substitute the special character for the joined array "el" in the string and compare with the first string.

In the first case this will give "hello" == "hello" -> True
In the second case this will give "hello" == "helol" -> False

I hope this helps and makes sense.